# If $X_1$ and $X_2$ are individually independent to $\{Z_k\}$ does it follow that their sum is too.

Tags: probability-theory

If $X_1$ and $X_2$ and $\{Z_k\}_{k}$ denote Random variables on a probability space and it holds that

1. $\{X_1\}\cup\{Z_k\}$ is a collection of independent r.v.s
2. $\{X_2\}\cup\{Z_k\}$ is a collection of independent r.v.s

**does it then hold that $\{X_1+X_2\}\cup\{Z_k\}_k$ is a collection of independent random variables?** We do not assume that $X_1$ and $X_2$ are independent.

We know that $\sigma(X_1+X_2) = \sigma(\sigma(X_1)\cup \sigma(X_2))$, however this doesn't say much?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. Let $A,B,C$ be pair-wise independent events with $P(A\cap B\cap C) \neq P(A)P(B)P(C)$. Let $X=I_A, Y=I_B$ and $Z=I_C$. Then the hypothesis is satisfied. If $X+Y$ is indepdent of $Z$ then we would have $E((X+Y)^{2}Z)=E(X+Y)^{2}EZ$. A little simplification of this equation gives $P(A\cap B\cap C) =P(A)P(B)P(C)$ which is not true.

For an eample of such events see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pairwise_independence

Comment: Right we get $P(A)P(C)+2P(A\cap B \cap C)+P(B)P(C) =E(XZ)+2E(XYZ)+E(YZ) = E((X+Y)^2Z) = (E(X)+E(X)E(Y)+E(Y))E(Z) = (P(A)+P(A)P(B)+P(B))P(C) = P(A)P(C)+P(A)P(B)P(C)+P(B)P(C)$ implying that $P(A\cap B\cap C) = P(A)P(B)P(C)$. Thanks!